# Populating Dropdown from static array

Tags: php, select, phalcon

How to populate Select element from static array (Phalcon / at controller level) ?

Comment: `foreach($arr as $key => $val) { echo "<option value=\"$key\">$val</option>"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a phalcon form element?

```
$select = new Select("telephoneType", array(
    'H' => 'Home',
    'C' => 'Cell'
));
```